# How can I execute a JavaScript function after Page Load is completed?

Tags: javascript

How can I execute a JavaScript function after Page Load is completed?

Comment: @Funky Dude: I think newbie questions are fine on Stack Overflow. When people Google it in future, they’ll end up here, and get some great answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `onload` event like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  // your code here.......
};
```

Comment: W3C has a newer recommended method for doing this that is far more powerful: element.addEventListener()

Comment: @Pullets Forever: Ok that is interesting.

Answer (score 7):

To get your onload handler to work cleanly in all browsers:

```
if (addEventListener in document) { // use W3C standard method
    document.addEventListener('load', yourFunction, false);
} else { // fall back to traditional method
    document.onload = yourFunction;
}
```

See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html for more detail

Answer (score 1):

Most JavaScript frameworks (e.g. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)) encapsulate similar functionality to this.

For example, in jQuery, passing a function of your own to the core jQuery function `$()` results in your function being called when the page’s DOM is loaded. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3.

This occurs before the `onload` event fires, as `onload` waits for all external files like images to be downloaded. Your JavaScript probably only needs the DOM to be ready; if so, this approach is preferable to waiting for `onload`.

Answer (score 0):

Event.observe(window, "onload", yourFunction);