# JavaScript in external file isn't running on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand one things with js. If I have my .js file and in HTML I have following code:

```
<head>
    <script src="skrypt.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
    Content
</body>
```

Does it mean that during first execution my skrypt.js will be performed ?

Because When I have in my skrypt.js code :

```
document.write("HelloWorld")
```

Output is "HelloWorld" but when I have in skrypt.js :

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
```

Page is blank and I have to use event :

```
<body onload="drawCanvas();">
</body>
```

Where drawCanvas() has the same code like in  external .js file.

So why document.write is working while canvas is not ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I execute a JavaScript function after Page Load is completed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261969/how-can-i-execute-a-javascript-function-after-page-load-is-completed)

Comment: its not a question how to execute code when load is completed but about difference why some code is executed and some not

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript files loaded in the head are processed before the DOM is ready. You'll need to wrap your function in window.onload, call it elsewhere after the page loads, or put the external file call in at the bottom of your page document, just before the closing body tag.

Comment: And not use `document.write`

Comment: That was probably just a test statement.

Comment: still don't understand why document.write("text") is performed but canvas is not

Comment: I mean I don't have to wrap document.wirite while I have to wrap canvas

Comment: Maybe because that method is forced to wait until the document is ready.